# Mac 10.10.5 throwing error sudo: gpasswd: command not found

Tags: macos, sudo

I have requirement to add jenkins user on mac mini to docker group and trying below

```
which sudo
/usr/bin/sudo
```

Not working

```
sudo gpasswd -a jenkins docker
```

Not working

```
/usr/bin/sudo gpasswd -a jenkins docker
sudo: gpasswd: command not found
```

And at `.bash_profile` entries

```
 export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/"
 export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:/sw/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
 export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/opt/x11/bin:$PATH
```

Current logged user is administrator on this Mac. I'm not sure what may be going wrong here ?

Thanks,
Vikram

Comment: I think you want `which gpasswd`... not `which sudo`.

Comment: It return empty value.

Comment: Then `gpassword` is not available in any of the directories in your PATH. Note that `gpassword` is not standard on OS X, so this is not particularly surprising.

Comment: Right, so that tells you there is no `gpasswd` installed; try `passwd` instead.

Comment: passwd won't help to add mac user to docker group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [How to add user to a group from Mac OS X command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/214004/how-to-add-user-to-a-group-from-mac-os-x-command-line)

answered in above link.

The command which I was trying is not applicable for Mac OS